# Does master theorem apply differently for $n$ with restrictions?

Tags: recurrence-relation, master-theorem

Given $T(1) = 1$ and $T(n) = 4T(n/2) +n^2$ for $n\geq 2$, can I solve the recurrence for $T$ by applying the master theorem with $a = 4$, $b = d = 2$?

This would give $T(n) = \Theta(n^2\log n)$.

Comment: I don't understand your title. Actually, I don't understand the question, either. What's stopping you reading off the answer from whatever form of the master theorem that you're using?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  This appears to be covered by our reference question, especially http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2823/755.  I suggest you work through the material in that question.  If that doesn't answer your question, please edit your question to clarify what specifically you are unsure about and why the standard material doesn't handle this, and the question can be considered to be re-opened.